# CC-Mode - Javadoc Comment Colors in C/C++

Tags: font-lock, c++, cc-mode, c-mode

I've been fiddling around a bit with CC-mode lately and figured that since I prefer to comment my functions/classes with javadoc-like syntax, I'd like to use the built-in comment highlighting provided by the corresponding `c-doc-comment-style`. This works rather well, it highlights something like this rather easily:

```
/** @brief This is function foo.
    @param a this is a parameter.
    @return I return this.
*/
int foo(unsigned a) {...}
```

However, I noticed that the comment suddenly changed color as well to a default one I don't really like. Any idea how to change that color back to the one defined by the current theme instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fiddling a bit longer with this, I think I figured it out. Adding the following snippet to my CC-mode init-configuration fixed this:

```
(defun my-cc-init-hook ()
  "Initialization hook for CC-mode runs before any other hooks."
  (setq c-doc-comment-style
    '((java-mode . javadoc)
      (pike-mode . autodoc)
      (c-mode    . javadoc)
      (c++-mode  . javadoc)))
  (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-doc-face
               (face-foreground font-lock-comment-face)))
(add-hook 'c-initialization-hook 'my-cc-init-hook)
```

This basically copies the foreground color of the comment face to the "doc"-face that the javadoc style defines. Any improvements to this is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the mapping to the comment style list:

```
(add-to-list 'c-doc-comment-style '(c++-mode . javadoc))
```

This is more portable and just extends the list instead of replacing it.

Comment: There's no need for the hook: the call to `add-to-list` could stand alone in the init file.  The hook will run every time you enter `c++-mode`, but `add-to-list` only adds to the list if the entry is not already there.  In other words, it'll do it's thing the first time you enter `c++-mode`, but do nothing over and over again for each subsequent time you enter `c++-mode`.