# Enable `cc-mode` documentation highlightning per minor mode

Tags: font-lock, comment, cc-mode

I am writing a [minor mode for enabling support for JML](https://github.com/wadoon/jml-mode/blob/master/jml-mode.el) within Java files.
I realized the syntax highlighting with `cc-mode`'s support for [documentation comments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Doc-Comments.html).

It works if I set `c-doc-comment-style` to `(jml javadoc)` in a file-local variable. Enabling JML doc comments interactively ([similar SO question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3762/cc-mode-javadoc-comment-colors-in-c-c)) with

```
(add-to-list 'c-doc-comment-style '(java-mode . jml))
(c-setup-doc-comment-style)
```

does not work. (The call of `c-setup-doc-comment-style` is explicit mention in the documentation.)

Has anyone experience with interactive en- and disabling doc comment highlighting in `cc-mode` and can give me a hint on my mistake?
Or should I file a bug report?

---

Via the great font-lock-studio, I found out that the `font-lock-keywords` 
are not updated by `c-setup-doc-comment-style`. 
In particular the entry:

```
(lambda
  (limit)
  (c-font-lock-doc-comments jml-start-multiline limit jml--font-lock-doc-comments))
  (0 nil)
```

is missing.

---

Tested with built-in `cc-mode` from `GNU Emacs 26.1.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2018-05-29`.